# Need help selecting multiple items in combobox in IE, using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer, combobox, automation

I am having an issue with one part of my automation job, and that is selecting ALL the options in a combobox, on a webpage, using VBA and IE.

This code selects ONE item in the combo box

```
Set frm = HTMLDoc.getElementsByName("UFG.USER_TYPES")(0)
   frm.Value = "AUT"
```

However, when I try to select multiple items, it just selects the last one, not all of them.

Here is the code from the web page

```
    <p  id="DispFormCollapsible.Rc10"class="formrow" >
    <span  id="DispFormCollapsible.Rc10.C1"  class="querytextleft">
    <label for="UFG.USER_TYPES" id="LabelForContro123"class = "simpletext" >
    Accessible Types:<span class="redstar">*</span></label></span>
    <span  id="DispFormCollapsible.Rc10.C2"  class="querytextright">
    <span class="labelColumn_combo">
    <span class="labelColumn_combi_brdr"> 
    <select  name= "UFG.USER_TYPES" multiple= "true" class = "dropdownexpandalbe"
     id="UFG.USER_TYPES" title = "Accessible Financial Transaction Types"> 
    <option value="AUT"   title="ACTIVE USER TYPE1" >TYPE1</option> 
    <option value="SET"   title="Selective User Type" >TYPE2</option> 
    <option value="TST"   title="Test User Type" >TEST3</option>
    </select></span></span>
    <input type ="hidden" name= "UFG.USER_TYPES" value="NULL" >
    </span></p>
```

Here is my VBA line to select an item

```
Set frm = HTMLDoc.getElementsByName("UFG.USER_TYPES")(0)
   frm.Value = "AUT"
```

What I need it to do, is select all the "option values" in the combobox.  I think it needs to be an array maybe, or some other way.  I've tried searching, but I'm getting nowhere.  Any help appreciated. Thx

Tried the following, but get an error 91 Block not set.  I've also tried using the Values "AUT" in the children, and when doing that I don't get an error, but it doesn not select anything.

```
With HTMLDoc.getElementsByName("Select")(0)
    .Children(1).Selected = True
    .Children(2).Selected = True
    .Children(3).Selected = True
End With
```

Also tried the following, this doesn't give an error, but only selects the first option in the list.

```
With HTMLDoc.getElementsByName("UFG.USER_TYPES")(0)
    .Children(AUT).Selected = True
    .Children(SET).Selected = True
    .Children(TST).Selected = True
End With
```

This is strange, when I use this code, it selects the first two in the list, but not the third.

```
With HTMLDoc.getElementsByName("UFG.USER_TYPES")(0)
    .Children(all).Selected = True
End With
```

Comment: tried this, but get an error 91 block not set.

Comment: also tried with "AUT" and again, nothing happens.

Comment: Can you manually select all?

Comment: yes on the page, you can "ctl" click each option in the combobox manually.  I just want my automation code to select all :)

Comment: you might try selenuim. Is the url private?

Answer (score 0):

```
With HTMLDoc.getElementsByName("UFG.USER_TYPES")(0)
    .Children(0).Selected = True
    .Children(1).Selected = True
    .Children(2).Selected = True
End With
```

The above code fixed it... whoopie!

Comment: Thanks for posting the solution for this issue. I suggest you to try to mark your own answer as an accepted answer for this question after 48 hrs, when it is available to mark. It can help other community members in future in similar kind of issues. Thanks for your understanding.